# Write to screen in the same line fortran

Tags: fortran

I am looking to output some numbers to the screen in Intel Fortran, By default Fortran writes a new line everytime I output something to the screen. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
PROGRAM sample
integer :: ind

do ind = 1,20
    write(*,*) ind
    !Some other stuff here
end do

END PROGRAM
```

I tried to use the no-advance option but it did not work:

```
PROGRAM sample
integer :: ind

do ind = 1,20
    write(*,*,advance='no') ind
    !Some other stuff here
end do
END PROGRAM
```

Ideally what I want is to output the following to the screen:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

All in the same line. Is there ant way of doing this in fortran?

Comment: Please, *never*, *never* say *"it did not work"*. It is not useful at all. Please always say what happened. I am sure you received some error message or something. These are important to show. You have already decent SO reputation so you should know how to ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not work with the format "*" (list directed). But it is OK with an explicit format :

```
program test
   implicit none
   integer :: ind
   do ind = 1,20
      write(*,'(1x,i0)',advance='no') ind
      !Some other stuff here
   end do
end program
```

Result :

```
[coul@localhost ~]$ gfortran test.f90
[coul@localhost ~]$ ./a.out
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20[coul@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: Interesting. I had tried something similar on my first attempts and it did not work. Now I took your solution and realized that in works in intel fortran "release mode" but not in debug mode. Any clue why?

Comment: With a debugger like gdb, this one will interact with the standard output file and then perturb  the normal output of the program, especially if you execute the loop instructions one by one...

Comment: I see. And I am assuming there are no easy workarounds to that. Thanks for your help.